# How to Debug an office 2007-addin with office 2010

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, office-interop

I want to develop a word addin that should run for word 2007 and word 2010. So I created a word 2007 addin project in visual studio. on my mashine there is (only) word 2010 installed. When I try to debug the addin from visual studio, I get the error message that this add in can only be debugged with word 2007.

Is there a way to debug a office (word) 2007 addin with office (word) 2010?

Thanks in advance
Tobias

Answer (score 4):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/1c9f6338-e08c-495e-92dd-c4a83ffd6fd4/ which suggests you Right click in the Add-in project properties; in the Debug tab, Start external program => Browse for the installed version of Word.