# Debugging Outlook 2010 plugin with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a C# Outlook plugin and I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Whenever I try to debug against Outlook 2010 I get the following error: `You cannot run or debug this project, because the required version of the microsoft office is not installed.`

I had the same issue with Office 2013 but that was fixed by installing the Office Tools for Visual Studio 2012. Is there something I need to install to get it to work with Office 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [How to Debug an office 2007-addin with office 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212664/how-to-debug-an-office-2007-addin-with-office-2010)

Basically on the project properties you have to go to debug and tell it to open outlook as the external program.